# Convert text to embroidery stitches in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am developing a product configurator in asp.net C# probabely like http://www.vistaprint.in/vp/ns/easypath/studio.aspx?template=446855~s1_BJD_BJX&ag=True&xnav=previews&xnid=image_112&rd=1

I am stuck on these 3 questions.

1. Users will upload a clear image with simple(no gradients) text on it. I would like to change this text on image to embroidery stitched text? Text can be straight line text or curved text or any other shape.
2. If it is not possible with text on image ,can I simply convert the text into embroidery stitched text? Text can be straight line text or curved text or any other shape.
3. Can this be done using some jquery or javascript or C# plugins? If yes,please suggest.

As I am new to product configurator ,I have no idea from where to start from
and require some helping hands.

Comment: Do you need real data for controlling an embroidery machine? This would be non-trivial. If you just want an image which has the appearance, you could probably use GIMP and script-fu for this. http://registry.gimp.org/node/26950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

One way I would go for this is to have different image for each letter a-z A-Z and also each digit 0-9. (With a transparent background)

1. When the user is done typing I would send an ajax request to the server with the user's input and the response would be an image with the text itself. (jQuery could be used for this purpose)
2. On the server side for each letter in the user's input I would fetch the appropriate image For example "a" would be [image]. (It is better for the letters to be with a transparent background).
3. Using something like this [Combine two Images into one new Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206510/combine-two-images-into-one-new-image) I would create the full text and than send it back to the client.
4. On the client side you would know roughly  where to put the new image on the canvas. /For example it has to be centred vertically and horizontally./

And finally if you want to curve, manipulate, etc. the text you can also use standart C# tools - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b575a03(v=vs.110).aspx) Also this SO answer - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11151457/1099945).

**Method 2**

Another way is to create /or use/ a custom font (One appropriate can be found [here](http://www.dafont.com/basicscratch.font) and [here](http://www.fonts.com/font/profonts/stina)) And render the image using it. Please check this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070365/how-to-generate-an-image-from-text-on-fly-at-runtime). If you need a more serious text manipulation, probably this method is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks bigman gyosifov !. I will try both the methods and choose the appropriate accordingly.

Comment: Please after that leave a comment for the community letting us know how it went :)