# Render curved arabic word in C# with correct ligatures

Tags: c#, string, unicode, arabic, system.drawing

I am working with code to create a custom image that displays words in curved text around a circle (think a CD label).

The code is not working with Arabic words. It utilizes the System.Drawing.Graphics class to do a character-by-character rendering, adjusting the angle as it goes. The problem is, once the word gets broken up into characters, they all become isolated form characters.

As an example (the English translation is Engagement):
[image]
It seems like the implementation would work with a positional-aware char object, but I couldn't find anything of that nature, nor could I find any method for rendering a curved word without going character-by-character.

How can I render Arabic words on a curved line while retaining positional forms for the characters?

Comment: Would this help you out at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803853/how-can-i-render-curved-text-into-a-bitmap

Comment: I think it could, but I'm having trouble knowing what data to pass to the function.

Comment: On second thought, no it can't because it goes character-by-character.

Answer (score 0):

Welp sorry for the late answer, but i think you may create a method to loop throgh the arabic characters and do what to do.

Suddenly i found this, which worked for my xna game very well
https://github.com/Konash/arabic-support-unity/blob/master/Assets/ArabicSupport/Scripts/ArabicSupport.cs